# Clone-ing a Vesuvan Doppelganger

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a [Vesuvan Doppelganger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Vesuvan%20Doppelganger) is in play having assumed the characteristics of, say, a [Royal Assassin](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Royal%20Assassin), would cloning the Doppelganger at this point be tantamount to having cast a second Doppelganger? (...that could then change into something else next turn, after spending a turn as another Royal Assassin, but with summoning sickness?)

Answer (score 4):

The Clone would enter the battlefield as a copy of whatever Vesuvian Doppelganger is cloning, with the Doppelganger's extra ability. In fact, the [rules about copying objects](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Copying_objects) have an example covering this specific scenario

> The copy’s copiable values become the copied information, as modified by the copy’s status (see rule 110.6). Objects that copy the object will use the new copiable values.
>
> > **Example:**  Vesuvan Doppelganger reads, "You may have Vesuvan Doppelganger enter the battlefield as a copy of any creature on the battlefield except it doesn’t copy that creature’s color and it gains ‘At the beginning of your upkeep, you may have this creature become a copy of target creature except it doesn’t copy that creature’s color. If you do, this creature gains this ability.’" A Vesuvan Doppelganger enters the battlefield as a copy of Runeclaw Bear (a 2/2 green Bear creature with no abilities). Then a Clone enters the battlefield as a copy of the Doppelganger. The Clone is a 2/2 blue Bear named Runeclaw Bear that has the Doppelganger’s upkeep-triggered ability.